# Google Analytics not filtering internal traffic

Tags: django, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I know there have been similar questions in the past but I have tried many solutions given online to no avail. I am just not able to hide internal traffic for Google Analytics on my Django site.

I am setting the filter from Admin->View->Filters. Have tried Predefined and Custom both with fixed IP as well as a regex pattern. (Yes, I have double checked my IP from whatismyip.com and I am using the right one)

I read somewhere that it takes time for the filters to come into effect, so even waited for 24 hours but I still see a lot of internal traffic.

Google Tag Assistant is also tracking the pages when I access them from internal IP (not sure if its supposed to know about the filters)

Not sure where could I be going wrong.

(I am using reverse proxy but hopefully that wouldn't change anything since the google analytics code is run on the client side)

Comment: Maybe you use IP anonymization in your tracking code ? Because that is applied before the filters, making them basically useless (unless you discard a whole range of addresses).

Comment: @Elike No I am using exactly the same tracking code that I got after sign up, without tweaking it.

Comment: You can also adapt [this approach](http://www.daniloaz.com/en/how-to-exclude-your-own-dynamic-ip-from-google-analytics/) from php to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use any filter on the default view (called 'All Website Data'). Create a separate view and then create a filter on it. That will work.

(After struggling with it for a few days, [this](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Filters/Why-am-I-still-showing-up-in-Real-time-reports/m-p/531226#M1099) response helped me with the above fix)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well, so here is what I found out.

Note that real time reporting can take up to 2hrs to catch up to and reflect analytics configuration changes such as the addition of filters.

### Possible solutions

1) As suggested in the other answer, leave the default view as default and create an additional view for the filters:

> The default view collects
>   all traffic. You need to create a new view for which you can apply
>   your filter. Check out item 3 here
>   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en
>
> How to add
>   a new view: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714?hl=en

2) Filter IP v6, not v4:

> Exclude the ipv6 address as mentioned in above post.  This is the one
>   that "what is my ip address" returns.  It's not the ipv4 syntax
>   (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)  However, I have noticed that wired machines that
>   stay connected seem to keep the same ipv6 IP (the 31 digit sequence),
>   however wireless accounts (mobile phones, tablets) tend to be dynamic.
>   However, as posted above if you use just the first 15 digits of the
>   sequence and use the "begins with" filter type, it will block
>   the devices using the same shared router (ie. internet router in your
>   home)

About filtering only the first 15 digits:

I think it is meant to filter the first four blocks, so if your IPv6 looks like `2601:191:c001:2f9:5c5a:1c20:61b6:675a`, then filter IP `that begins with` `2601:191:c001:2f9:`.

---

Information found [here](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Filters/Why-am-I-still-showing-up-in-Real-time-reports/td-p/527075).